# React pass props to children

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to pass extra props to this.props.children, I saw this answer [how to pass props to children with React.cloneElement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46445048/how-to-pass-props-to-children-with-react-cloneelement)

and from some reason although I'm not getting any error I can't see the prop

So I have this state

```
this.state = {
    open: true
}
```

and I want to pass it down to this.props.children, and this is what I've done so far:

```
{
    React.Children.map(this.props.children, child =>
        React.cloneElement(child, {sidebarState: this.state.open}))
}
```

and when I'm console.logging this.props on the children I can't see my new props.

--- EDIT ---
In the children it looks like this:

```
render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    // other code
}
```

BTW I'm using react 16.0

Comment: where you put the console inside children, can you show the code?

Comment: I've added it but I don't know if it will be much of a help

Comment: have you tried using jsx? its easier to specify props using jsx syntax

Comment: I'm always getting a different component there so I'm not sure how jsx will do the job here

Answer (score 7):

Here is an example.

Before (without passing props down to the `children`):

```
    <div className="layout">
      {children}
    </div>
```

After (passing extra `props1` and `props2` props to every child):

```
    <div className="layout">
      {
        React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
          return React.cloneElement(child, {
            props1: 1,
            props2: 2,
          });
        })
      }
    </div>
```

> `props1` and `props2` get merged with the existing props for every child.

Regarding TypeScript types, you have to use `React.ReactElement` instead of `React.ReactNode` or the TS compiler will complain at `React.Children.map` (or ts-ignore it):

```
type Props = {
  children: React.ReactElement;
};
```

---

> See https://medium.com/better-programming/passing-data-to-props-children-in-react-5399baea0356 for more explanation, that helped me a lot to understand how to do it! (#mediumPaywall)

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to pass props to children:

**Children as function**

Instead of being a React element, children can be a function.

Call the children function:

```
const List = ({ children, sidebarState }) => (
  <ul>
  {
    children(sidebarState)
  }
  </ul>
);
```

Passing the children a function:

```
<List sidebarState={sidebarState}>
  {
    (sidebarState) => (
      <Item sidebarState={sidebarState} />
    )
  }
</List>
```

*Working example:*

```js
const { Component } = React;

const Item = ({ sidebarState }) => (
  <li>{sidebarState ? 'open' : 'close'}</li>
);

const List = ({ children, sidebarState }) => (
  <ul>
  {
    children(sidebarState)
  }
  </ul>
);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
        sidebarState: true
    }
  }
  
  toggleOpen = () => this.setState((prevState) => ({
    sidebarState: !prevState.sidebarState
  }));
  
  render() {
    const { sidebarState } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleOpen}>Toggle</button>
        
        <List sidebarState={sidebarState}>
          {
            (sidebarState) => (
              <Item sidebarState={sidebarState} />
            )
          }
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```

**React.cloneElement**

*Working example:*

```js
const { Component } = React;

const Item1 = ({ sidebarState }) => (
  <li>{sidebarState ? 'open' : 'close'}</li>
);

const Item2 = ({ sidebarState }) => (
  <li>{sidebarState ? 'open' : 'close'}</li>
);

const List = ({ children, sidebarState }) => (
  <ul>
  {
    React.Children.map(children, (child) => React.cloneElement(child, { sidebarState }))
  }
  </ul>
);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    
    this.state = {
        sidebarState: true
    }
  }
  
  toggleOpen = () => this.setState((prevState) => ({
    sidebarState: !prevState.sidebarState
  }));
  
  render() {
    const { sidebarState } = this.state;
    
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.toggleOpen}>Toggle</button>
        
        <List sidebarState={sidebarState}>
          <Item1 />

          <Item2 />
        </List>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```