# How to access value passed to {children} in React functional components with no "concrete" child element?

Tags: reactjs

So I have the following situation (all are functional components).
`<Main>`, where it returns

```
<Comp A>
<Comp B>
...
{children}
...
```

I have a piece of info that I want to use in both `<Comp A>` and sometimes, {children} - I can do it in `<Comp A>` and the specific {children} separately, but that seems a bit redundant to me. I'm trying to hit that API once in `<Main>`, and pass the info to both `<Comp A>` and {children}.[React pass props to children](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46988090/react-pass-props-to-children) and have followed along several solutions, but I'm having trouble accessing the data passed to children.

The structure of my use case might be important here: I'm trying to access the data in `<Other Comp>`, which is defined as

```
<Main>
<div>blablabla</div>
</Main>
```

And my goal is to say, be able to render whatever is passed in the "blablabla" part of the code. So the `<Other Comp>` isn't technically a child of Main, but it is filling in the {children} part. Wonder if this is possible at all? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using a state managing tool like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/)? That way you can set your data in the store and grab it from different places in your application. This is only a suggestion as I do not know the entire scope of your application.

Comment: @tomerpacific I'll check that out! I'm not too familiar with Redux but if this sounds like a good use case for that I am willing to look into it!

Answer (score 1):

I guess Redux would be kinda "overkill" for this case. Using React [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) API will be a great option. Just follow these simple steps to create a [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) Context:

**1. Create a new file, for example** `Context.js`

```
/* Context.js */ 
import React, { createContext } from "react"

export const InfoContext = createContext()

// HOC Component
const MyContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
  // define your 'info' value (you can define many values)
  const info = "your info"

  return (
    <InfoContext.Provider
      value={{
        info
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </InfoContext.Provider>
  )
}

export default MyContextProvider
```

**2. Wrap your components `or (<Main> if you like)` with this HOC**  `MyContextProvider`

```js
<MyContextProvider>
   ...
   <Comp A>
   <Comp B>
   ...
</MyContextProvider>
```

**3. Now, you can access** `info` **value anywhere in `<Comp A>` | `<Comp B>` with** [useContext](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html) **Hook like this:**

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react"
import { InfoContext } from "../Context"

const CompA = () => {
  const { info } = useContext(InfoContext)

  return <h1>{info}</h1>
}

export default CompA
```

[image: Edit react useContext hook]