# Is there a way to give a prop from a container to unknown children?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

I am trying to create a collapsable container component that could be reused for different parts of a form in order to show the fields or a summary of that section. In my case, each container would contain a Form object passed as a child to that container. The base of my code goes as follows :

```
function CollapsableContainer({ title, children }: CollapsableContainerProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

  return (
    <div className="comp-collapsable-container">
      {isOpen ? (
        {children}
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="header-section">
            <Typography variant="h6">
              {title}
            </Typography>
            <Button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)} startIcon={<EditIcon />}>
              Modify
            </Button>
          </div>

          <div className="summary-section">
              /* Summary here */
          </div>
        </>
      )}

    </div>
  )
}
```

I am wondering if it's possible to pass setIsOpen to the children in order to allow the container to collapse once the user pressed a button that that child would contain instead of having to replicate that behaviour multiple times. (Basically without copy/pasting my code)

To give more context, a child would look something like this, where the setIsOpen would be added to the onSubmit function :

```
<Formik
  initialValues={initialValues}
  validationSchema={validationSchema}
  onSubmit={onSubmit}
>
  <Form>
    <FormikTextField
      id="name"
      name="name"
      label="name"
      fullWidth
      required
    />

    <FormikTextField
      id="description"
      name="description"
      label="description"
      fullWidth
      required
    />
  </Form>
</Formik>
```

Thank you for any help or suggestion!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to create a CodeSandbox to you.

You have to type your CollapsableContainerProps as follows. You are stating that children will require props that extend the interface RequiresSetIsOpenProps. This is from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59381632/12833553).

```
interface RequiresSetIsOpenProps {
  setIsOpen?: Dispatch<SetStateAction<boolean>>;
}

interface CollapsableContainerProps {
  title: string;
  children:
    | React.ReactElement<RequiresSetIsOpenProps>
    | React.ReactElement<RequiresSetIsOpenProps>[];
}
```

Then, you can create any sort of child components you want that satisfy this condition:

```
interface SomeButtonProps {
  // add your other child props here.
  title: string;
}

function SomeButton(props: RequiresSetIsOpenProps & SomeButtonProps) {
  const { setIsOpen, title } = props;

  function handleClick() {
    if (setIsOpen !== undefined) setIsOpen(false);
  }

  return <button onClick={handleClick}>{title}</button>;
}
```

Finally, inside your CollapsableContainer you have to apply the setIsOpen function to each of the children. I got this from another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59029736/12833553). You are telling React to copy whatever children were passed in and slap the setIsOpen function on top of the existing props.

```
function CollapsableContainer({ title, children }: CollapsableContainerProps) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="comp-collapsable-container">
      {isOpen ? (
        React.Children.map(children, (child) => {
          return React.cloneElement(child, {
            setIsOpen: setIsOpen
          });
        })
      ) : (
        <>
          <div className="header-section">
            <h6>{title}</h6>
            <button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}>Modify</button>
          </div>

          <div className="summary-section">/* Summary here */</div>
        </>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is the [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-architecture-rqnocn?file=/src/App.tsx:712-1357) to check it out! I hope this helps!